# C open files : number of opened file

Tags: c, iostream, yacc, lex

ALL,

is there any solution to get the number of opened files in my program c

the probleme is: while the parsing of a list of file with lex and yacc

yyin recieve an fopen of the current stream, at the end (yywrap) i close the yyin using the fclose : so normally the number of th opened files equal to zero.
for some examples i get this error exception when i call an fopen(many opned files)

so my question is how do i get from a system command the number of opned files in order to debug this problem.

thnks for help

Comment: It would probably help to post some code.

Comment: i resolved my problem: there is a system function called openfiles it describe for your process the liste of opened files.
an uneeded fopen for duplicated includes causes this problem thnks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use *only* `fopen` and `fclose`, then something that you're looking for (I think) might be achieved with a trick like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int open_files = 0;

FILE *fopen_counting(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *v;
    if((v = fopen(path,mode)) != NULL) ++open_files;
    return v;
}

int fclose_counting(FILE *fp)
{
    int v;
    if((v = fclose(fp)) != EOF) --open_files;
    return v;
}

#define fopen(x,y) fopen_counting(x,y)
#define fclose(x) fclose_counting(x)
```

Of course, a snippet like this will only affect the code over which you have control : it will have to be `#include`d before any calls to `fopen` or `fclose` are made - otherwise, the original functions will be called instead of your replacements.

When it comes to a system function that would return the current number of open file descriptors, I'm unfortunately not aware of such thing. But what's stopping you from running your application under a debugger, setting a breakpoint on `fopen`, and simply using an OS tool to check that number? On Linux, the number of open file descriptors in a process is equal to the number of entries in the directory `/proc/$PID/fd` - by doing it this way, you'll even know which actual file is assigned to which file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integer, set it equal to `0` and increment it each time you use `fopen` and decrement it each time you use `fclose`.

```
file *fp;                  
int files_opened = 0;      //number of open files

if(!(fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"))) //open file
{
                           //could not open file
}
else files_opened++;       //we opened a file so increment files_opened
printf("\n%d files are currently open.", files_opened); //display how many files currently open
if(!(fclose(fp) != EOF)))  //close file
{
    //could not close file
}
else files_opened--;       //we closed a file so decrement files_opened
printf("\n%d files are currently open.", files_opened); //display how many files currently open
```

Comment: thnks it looks simple, i ask if i can get this information from the system like this function whitch returns the error on opening file strerror(errno)

Comment: I updated my answer, you're going to have to keep track of it yourself. This is how I would do it. But you're situation may be different.

Comment: i also update my question for you , it isn't so evident as you think.

Comment: I updated my answer again. If you increment / decrement `files_opened` every time you call `fclose` or `fopen` then `files_opened` will be equal to the amount of files you currently have open. `printf("\n%d files are currently open.", files_opened);` will output that number to the console.